# Divisors of positive integer

Tags: sequences-and-series

If the sum of all the divisors of a positive integer $n$ (including $1$ and $n$) is $75$.Then find the sum of reciprocal of the divisors

The options are:-
(a)${75\over k}$      (b)${75\over n}$      (c)${1\over n}$    (d)${1\over 75}$

Comment: What are your guesses? Could you eliminate at least one of the option. Give reasons. Give evidence that you though over the problem. Attempt to simply pass the problem to others is considered rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the divisors be $d_1, ..., d_k$ in increasing order.
Then, we are given that $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} d_i = 75$$
We want to find out $$A:=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{d_i}$$
Note that, $$nA = n\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{d_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{n}{d_i} = \sum_{i=k}^{1}d_i = \sum_{i=1}^{k}d_i = 75$$ because, $\frac{n}{d_1}=\frac{n}{1}=n=d_k$, $\frac{n}{d_2}=d_{k-1}$, etc.

Hence, $A = \frac{75}{n}$, i.e, **option (b)** is correct

Answer (score 1):

Answer is b, because 
i -> n/i - bijection of the divisors set